# Chrome automatically downloading PDF

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

```
 <div align="justify" style="height: 500px; border: 1px solid #ccc;
 overflow: auto;">
                    <object data="/policy/download/#zoom=65,65,720" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="500"></object>
                   </div>
```

thats piece of code, am using django 2.2 and python 3.6.7.
So that code is for sake of viewing https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/related?hl=en via pdf viewer extension.
However, chrome is causing problem by auto downloading the pdf. Only chrome not firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This is a chrome browser setting - 'Download PDF files instead of automatically opening them in Chrome' is a toggle in the options. The user would have to have this turned off for this to work the same as Firefox.

You are unable to change this behaviour unfortunately.